# Django calls wrong path after calling long path first

Tags: python, django

I have these 3 paths in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("stuff/<str:name>/", views.stuff),
    path("stuff/<str:name>/<str:color>/", views.colored_stuff),
    path("stuff/<str:name>/<str:color>/<str:size>/", views.sized_colored_stuff),

]
```

and these corresponding methods in views.py:

```
def stuff(request, name):
    ...

def colored_stuff(request, name, color):
    ...

def sized_colored_stuff(request, name, color, size):
    ...
```

If I call https://example.com/stuff/Oak/Red/Big, the third path is called, which makes sense. However, then when I try to hit https://example.com/stuff/Birch then request still goes to the third path instead of the first.  Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: Try adding a slash at the end of urls

Comment: @RafaelC They are not regex patterns. See the new [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path) function.

Comment: It looks fine to me. Is this your real code or some hypothetical example?

Comment: Nvm figured it out.  I needed to switch the order of some paths that came before. Doh.  Thanks all!

Comment: write path like this `path("stuff/<name>/<color>/<size>/", views.sized_colored_stuff)`